# React - unexpected css token with Webpack/babel-register

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-register

In my React app, I'd like to use `style-loader`/`css-loader` with Webpack to import a stylesheet from another Node module, `react-quill` - https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill. I've obviously not configured it correctly, though, as my app throws the error

```
.ql-container {
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/username/Desktop/Development/project/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/Development/project/src/Quill/Quill.jsx:2:1)
```

Following the `react-quill` docs, I've imported the stylesheet into my `Quill.jsx` component using

```
import theme from 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
```

and my Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: './public/bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/, 
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets:['react','es2015','stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and looking at my `bundle.js`, I can see that the Quill stylesheet was included in the build.

Finally, one of the errors refers to `babel-register`, which I'm using in development to handle on-the-fly transpiling for server-side rendering - it appears as

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015','react','stage-2']
})
```

Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: you have to use `webpack` on server too, if you don't bundle your server, you can't handle different imports types. Don't use babel register, replace it with a webpack configuration

Comment: I do have a Webpack server config as well - I added style/css loaders there as well, but when I tried to build, this returned a `window is not defined` error for `return window && document && document.all && !window.atob;` which comes from `css-loader`. Is there a Webpack babel-loader preset that I need to set to allow references to `window`/`document` on the server?

Comment: drop `babel-register`, you don't need it. Then, change your style loader with something like: https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader

Comment: I'll try that out a little later, will let you know. Thanks for the advice.